# How to get JSON data with two dynamic variables?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, dynamic, jsx

It's my first post here so if I'm doing something wrong please tell me!
I'm still learning React and am working on a project for university.

I'm trying to get the length from my JSON while having two dynamic variables.

my JSON:

```
"data": { 
  "Java1": {
   "Arrays": {
     "Aufgabe1": {answer:"option1", option1:"A", option2:"B", option3:"C", option4:"D", question:"Foo?"},
     "Aufgabe2": {answer:"option2", option1:"A", option2:"B", option3:"C", option4:"D", question:"bar?"}
     },
   "Schleifen": {
     "Aufgabe1": {answer:"option1", option1:"A", option2:"B", option3:"C", option4:"D", question:"Foo?"},
     "Aufgabe2": {answer:"option2", option1:"A", option2:"B", option3:"C", option4:"D", question:"bar?"}
       }
   },
  "Java2": {
    "Streams": {
      "Aufgabe1": {answer:"option1", option1:"A", option2:"B", option3:"C", option4:"D", question:"Foo?"},
      "Aufgabe2": {answer:"option2", option1:"A", option2:"B", option3:"C", option4:"D", question:"bar?"}
      },
    "Vererbung": {
      "Aufgabe1": {answer:"option1", option1:"A", option2:"B", option3:"C", option4:"D", question:"Foo?"},
      "Aufgabe2": {answer:"option2", option1:"A", option2:"B", option3:"C", option4:"D", question:"bar?"}
      }
    }
}
```

How I tried getting it:

```
getData = (e) => {
  const dropdown1 = this.state.selectedOption.value;           // Java1
  const dropdown2 = this.state.selectedOption2.value;          // Arrays
  const temp = Object.keys(this.state.data[dropdown1]).length;
  console.log("dataLength: ", temp);                           // 2
};
```

This code works, but it only gives me the length of `Java1`
What I need though, is the length of e.g. Arrays and I have no clue how to get that since `Java1` & `Arrays` are dynamically chosen from two dropdowns.

I have tried some variations like:

`const temp = Object.keys(this.state.data[dropdown1].[dropdown2]).length;`

or

`const temp = Object.keys(this.state.data[dropdown1.[dropdown2]]).length;`

but it won't work. (obviously I guess)
I cant find any solution or example to this problem (maybe because of language barrier).
So if you guys have any idea of how I can get there, I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes I got it now, thanks alot !